# Python stack containing objects changing automatically

Tags: python, stack

I used the following stack class in Python to store objects of another class.

```
class Stack :
 def __init__(self) :
   self.items = []

 def push(self, item) :
   self.items.append(item)

 def pop(self) :
   return self.items.pop()

 def isEmpty(self) :
   return (self.items == []) 
scopeStack=Stack();
object1=AnotherClass();
object1.value=2;
scopeStack.push(object1);
```

On changing the contents of the object object1 outside the stack, the contents of the stack's object changed too.

```
 object1.value=3;
 obj=scopeStack.pop();
 print obj.value; #gives output 3
```

What should I do to NOT have this dynamic binding between a local variable and the stack's inner variables?

Comment: How would you expect Python to clone an arbitrary object?

Comment: What should I do to have such a thing in Python then?

Comment: You could try to use `deepcopy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `copy` module found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html). What you are looking for is called `copy.deepcopy()`.

Example:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

x = Obj(5)
y = copy.deepcopy(x)

print 'x:', x.value
print 'y:', y.value

x.value = 3

print 'x:', x.value
print 'y:', y.value
```

Output:

```
x: 5
y: 5
x: 3
y: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a dynamic binding, it's just multiple references to the same object.  When you do `scopeStack.push(object1)`, you push that object onto the stack -- not the name of the object, or the object's contents, but the object itself.  If you later modify that object, its modifications will show up anywhere there is a  reference to it.

If you want the version on the stack to be independent, then you need to make a copy of it and push the copy.  You could try using the `copy` module for this, but if your object is an instance of a custom class, you may need to write your own copy mechanism for that class.  Python can't automatically know how to copy instances of any custom class you create.

Comment: I am new to Python, I used to do this in Java and C++. It is a custom class. How should I make a copy module for this? Can I have such a library stack for my purposes?

Comment: As stated in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for the `copy` module, you can use the `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` methods.  However, if your object is just a simple collection of Python builtin types, `copy.deepcopy` may work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a copy of the objects, you need to copy or deepcopy the objects. Look at the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module.